# Calculating performance scores by subtracting the Shapley feature effects from predictions

Tags: interaction, boosting, importance, shapley-value

One of my friends has done the following:
He trained an XGBoost model let's call it `Model 1` and then calculated the feature effects using Shapley for the different features, let's say `Feature_1, Feature_2, Feature_3`. He then calculated the performance scores using the following combinations:

- `Prediction 1 = Effect Feature_1 + Effect Feature_2 + Effect Feature_3`
- `Prediction 2 = Effect Feature_1 + Effect Feature_2`
- `Prediction 3 = Effect Feature_1 + Effect Feature_3`

He found out that `Prediction 3` is the one that it is better than all in terms of performance. For me it's wrong what he did since XGBoost is a correlation model and by changing the training data you change the correlation among the features so if you train a model using only the `Feature_1 and Feature_3` then the predictions will not be equal to `Prediction 3`.

I was planning to prepare a dummy example for him by training a model `Model 2` with only the `Feature_1 and Feature_3` and show that the predictions of `Model 2` are not equal to `Prediction 3` but I wanted to ask the following:

- Do you have any resource that can explain it further and in a more
  scientifically sound way?
- And lastly but most importantly, is there a case where what he did actually holds true?

Thank you!

Comment: Shapley values are typically used as an interpretive tool and have not in my experience and reading been used 'as' components of creating finalized predictive values.  Are you looking to find an argument to _not_ use Shapley values in this way?  Or, rather, you more focused on the difference between what a re-fit `Model 2` would do in terms of prediction versus what using components of `Model 1` do?

Comment: I think both are interesting questions. What I was initially thinking was the latter question of yours. Also thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

Overall, agree that using Shapley values to choose a subset of features is not the same as estimating something like *model 2* with just those features.

For example, assume I've got a model like this for *model 1* (using R's `datasets::mtcars`)

`model_1 <- lm(mpg ~ am + vs + cyl, data = mtcars)`

I can get Shapley values (using method in the `{shapr}` package) by

```
set.seed(11042022)

lm_shapr <- shapr::shapr(mtcars[c("vs", "am", "cyl")], model_1)

lm_explain <- shapr::explain(mtcars |> subset(select = c(vs, am, cyl)), 
                             lm_shapr, approach = "empirical", prediction_zero = mean(mtcars$mpg))

shap_preds <- lm_explain$dt
```

Which produces a result like:

```
> shap_preds |> head()
       none        am        vs        cyl
1: 20.09063  2.330967 -1.556853  0.8572712
2: 20.09063  2.330967 -1.556853  0.8572712
3: 20.09063  2.322544  2.031903  2.8468138
4: 20.09063 -1.560581  2.144306 -0.6842069
5: 20.09062 -1.563329 -1.612503 -2.4945257
6: 20.09063 -1.560581  2.144306 -0.6842069
```

It so happens that the highest prediction is combining *am* and *cyl* like so:

```
shap_preds |> transform(comb = am + cyl) |> subset(select = comb) |> cor(mtcars$mpg)
         [,1]
cor 0.8298505
```

which ostensibly performs better than all three variables:

```
> shap_preds |> transform(comb = cyl + vs + cyl) |> subset(select = comb) |> 
    cor(mtcars$mpg)
         [,1]
cor 0.8085383
```

A similar situation as to that described above, but with a linear model.

One complication is that Shapley values are designed to approximate the effect of a variable's impact across combinations of 'different coalitions of players' or different features being included or excluded in terms of their impact.

That means each variable's effect is an approximation and doesn't necessarily sum up to the predicted value.  The actual correlation between all 3 variables, from the full model, with the outcome is:

```
> predict(model_1) |> cor(mtcars$mpg)
[1] 0.8729131
```

And, in fact, when the model is refit with the two predictors considered best from the last model, as you had suggested above, the refit model (i.e., *model 2*) changes in a way that does not look like *model 1*'s Shapley values and effectively recovers the same correlation with the outcome.

```
> lm(mpg ~ am + cyl, data = mtcars) |> predict() |> cor(mtcars$mpg)
[1] 0.8712138
```

> Do you have any resource that can explain it further and in a more
> scientifically sound way?

The Shapley value literature is fairly complex but the idea is, again, that Shapley values try to approximate what the effect the model has when a feature is omitted compared to when it is included which, for most implementations, is conditional on the model as estimated.  As I noted in the comment above, these values are intended for explanation purposes to understand model predictions for complex functions like *xgboost* and not for selection of features.

> And lastly but most importantly, is there a case where what he did actually holds true?

I believe it would in conditions where the features are completely uncorrelated with one another.  I suspect that in any other situation that some form of the above would occur.